# \bidi@@RTLfootnotetext@font undefined to use xepersian

Tags: bidi, xepersian

I'm gonna run the following test code by MikTeX 2.9:

```
% !TeX document-id = {8717fdc4-fa28-4491-9dd0-c8b7338defce}
% !TeX program = xelatex
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{xepersian} 
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{XB Niloofar} 

\begin{document} 
متن آزمایشی
\end{document}
```

An error is thrown as:

> \bidi@@RTLfootnotetext@font undefined.
>   \renewcommand*{\bidi@@RTLfootnotetext@font}

Comment: Is the selected font available in your system?

Comment: @Roboticist: As I checked the font was not available. So I've added and now the error is changed to `Undefined control sequence. \luatex_if_engine:T` and `Font \EU2/lmr/m/n/10=file:lmroman10-regular:script=latn;+trep;+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad. \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont`

Comment: For the first error: just update `l3-kernel` and `l3-packages` packages.

Comment: @Roboticist: Sorry, but errors are changed again: `Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \__cs_generate_from_signature:nnNNNn. \int_case:nnn` and `Undefined control sequence. \int_case:nnn`

Comment: Add `\usepackage{expl3} \ExplSyntaxOn \cs_set_eq:NN \str_case:nnn \str_case:nn \cs_set_eq:NN \str_case_x:nnn \str_case_x:nnF \ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: @Roboticist: I have this now: `Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \usepackage{xepersian}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of all unnecessary packages and commands, as following:

```
% !TeX document-id = {8717fdc4-fa28-4491-9dd0-c8b7338defce}
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xepersian} 
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document} 
    متن آزمایشی
\end{document}
```

It must work for you.